# Convert getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection($type) from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, singleton, conversion

I need to convert some singleton method calls from Magento 1 to Magento 2. Specifically `Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);`
How can I do this in M2? I know that I should first instantiate object manager, but everything after that is to me unknown. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by using:

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER) -> getObjectManager();
$rc = $om->get("\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection");
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer a bit more?  At least include the line that defines `$om`

Comment: Yes and I will also accept it. As soon as SO allows.

Comment: this feels dirty, are you sure this is Magento's recommended/verified way of calling it?

Comment: This is a good way to get a singleton, yes.

Answer (score 4):

**Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection** resource connection for M2 for both read/write.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
) {
   $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
}
```

Use following way:

```
$connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
$sql = "SELECT increment_id FROM sales_shipment WHERE order_id = '$orderId'";
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

Comment: I have this error when I try to create the ResourceConnection:
Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\ConfigInterface, none given

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: Do you create the instance of your actual class by ```new``` operator?

Comment: Yes, I used "new" keyword to create it.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic don't use "new", Always use DI.

Answer (score 3):

Not recommended but short Magento 2 alternative:

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::class)->getConnection($resource);
```

Recommended and common approach:

Add `Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection` as a dependency to constructor of class where you need to use it, assign it to property and then use property to get connection.

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection)
{
    $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
}

public function doSmth()
{
    ...$this->resourceConnection->getConnection($resource)...
}
```